# Typescript class decorator, force target the class to extend another class

Tags: typescript, decorator

I'm trying to write a class decorator which enforces the target class to extends another class.

Hypothetical example:

```
@Component
class MyComponent extends WebComponent
{
}
```

I want the `@Component` decorator to enforce the target class to extend on `WebComponent`.

I've tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work. I thouht it would be something as simple as this:

```
export function Component(options: ComponentConstructorOptions)
{
    return <T extends WebComponent>(target: T): T => {
        console.log(target);
        
        return target;
    };
}
```

So, if `MyComponent` does NOT extend on `WebComponent`, I want the typescript compilation to fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the fix by accident. It turned out to be as simple as using `typeof` in the function signature of the decorator:

```
return (target: typeof WebComponent) => {
    console.log(target);
};
```